# angularjs passing scope between routes

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, scope, angular-routing

i want to do something like :

```
1. Set $scope.val = <Some dynamic data> 
2. Click a link and be routed to a new template (with the same controller). 
3. $scope.val should still be the same value as it was on the last page.
```

Is somehow persisting data for the scope the right way to go about this, or is there some other way? Can you even create a controller that has a persisted scope between routes, except for saving it in a database of course.

Comment: not in database but cookies or localStorage can help

Comment: Hi Nimesh did you figure this out? A js fiddle or a plunker would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between controllers but not with the simple `$scope`.

You can use [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for this task.

A controller gets recreated whenever you access a new route. But a service is a singleton in your app. So data which is stored in a service can be accessed from every new controller.

Your service can be very simple and just return an empty object:

```
app.factory('sharedData', function() {
  return {
    name: 'Daniel'
  };
});
```

Then in your controller you can simple set this data object from the service to `$scope`.

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, sharedData) {
  $scope.data = sharedData;
});
```

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8amgfgQ9UbcNLfkzjo7X?p=preview)

Comment: can you please give one demo dynamic array pushing using service ?

Comment: The question was answered with a working Plunker. Now you add to your question. What's next? Can you please make my website?

Comment: i want to push dynamic array items from current page(supposed to route1.html) and get it to second page(assumed route2.html) in your demo ...

Answer (score 1):

You could attach data to the 
[$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope), but you want to use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

A service provides a method to keep data across the lifetime of the angular app. It's a way to communicate data across the controllers in a consistent way.

Create a service like this:

```
var DynamicData = angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('GetDynamicData', function () {
    $scope.data = [];
    $http.get('yourApiUrl/data.json').then(function(res){
     $scope.data = res.data;
    });
});
```

Then you can use this service in other controllers, like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['GetDynamicData']);
 myApp.controller('DataController', function ($scope, GetDynamicData) {
    //provide some business logic on $scope.data

 }
});
```

You can get some dynamic data with a service (using  and then inject that service in a controller where you want to use that data. Check out [the provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please create demo with plunkr and share link ?

Comment: Can you please give example of pushing static array items using service like above one ?